# How do I substitute characters around a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, replace, bbcode, substitution

I'm trying to write a ruby script to turn a small markup language I wrote into HTML, but I can't figure out how to parse links. It's basically a trimmed down version of BBCode, so for example, if someone enters `[i]{text}[/i]`, I use `[i]{text}[/i].gsub('[i]','<i>').gsub('[/i]','</i>'`. I can't figure out how to parse links, though. How would I turn `[url=website.com]site[/url]` into `<a href="website.com">site</a>`? I'm not using a premade BBCode parser because there are a few tags that are different, and I don't want people to use some of the tags such as `[img][/img]`.

Comment: [bb-ruby](http://bb-ruby.rubyforge.org/) seems to allow you to specify only certain tags to use, why not use that?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I didn't know that. I'll use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Very naïvely:

```
s.gsub(/\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/) { "<a href='#{$1}'>#{$2}</a>" }
```

HTML injection would be quite easy. The point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/13989) (write a proper parser) still applies to what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **kch** by using a regular expression but if you want to wrap your head around it using **gsub()** like you've been doing...

```
s = "[url=website.com]site[/url]"
s2 = s.gsub('[url=','<a href="').gsub('[/url]','</a>').gsub(']','">')
```